importing a file from another package isnt working
I want to import the Recipe class into my user.dart file, but i cant. I tried to create a path in the pubspac.yaml, but still it doesnt work.
Here is my package arch

I have a file inside the recipe_repository that i want to import inside a file inside the user_repository. each one recipe/user_repository has a pubspac.yaml.

packages should not be at the same level as the main project's pubspec.yaml... it should be up one level.
So you'll have packages, which contains main, recipe, user, and they each have pubspec.yaml and others. There won't be a pubspec.yaml at the top, although I recommend you use Melos and that'll need a melos.yaml at the top.

May i ask why it shouldn't be at the same level? And thx for the answer!

I'm confused.  My answer says to put all your packages at the same level.

you said "packages should not be at the same level as the main project's pubspec.yaml... it should be up one level."

I meant the "packages" directory.
